# How real-time are Twitter search API results?

Tags: twitter

I'm wondering how "real-time" are the results from http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q= as I can't find any clear indication on that from Twitter.

I mean, is there a guaranteed lag time?

Answer (score 2):

I get hours of delays from recent tweets using the search API

Answer (score 1):

I have one application which queries the public timeline given a GPS coordinate pair, and a radius in km or miles depending on where the user is from. The results I get back are often < 1 second for items just added (i.e., with a big radius so we get more fresh results). But there is no guarantee, they could be old as sin.

Comment: are you using search.twitter.com for that?

Comment: Yes.<11+ characters to make SO happy>

Answer (score 0):

- @Al Pascual is correct. Results from the search API will be delayed.
- OTOH, Twitter's new Phoenix search is especially fast.

  - Please see here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21868/15489